# How to get Cookies?

Tags: windows, perl, httpcookie

Using the WWW::Mechanize and HTTP::Cookies how would I extract the cookie past in the response from the server?

```
#usr/bin/perl 
#MagicLogin.pl

use warnings;
use strict;

use Win32::IE::Mechanize;
use HTTP::Message;
use WWW::Mechanize;
use HTTP::Request::Form;
use HTML::TreeBuilder 3.0;



my $url = 'http://magic.dstcorp.net/MagicDST/';

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new(cookie_jar => {});
$mech->agent_alias('Windows IE 6');

my $cookie_jar = new HTTP::Cookies;


my $res = $mech->get($url);
my $tree = new HTML::TreeBuilder;
$tree->parse($res->content);
$tree->eof;

my @forms = $tree->find_by_tag_name('form') or die "No form available";

my $f = HTTP::Request::Form->new($forms[0], $url);
my @fields = $f->allfields;
my $name = $f->name;
my $links = $f->link;
my $buttons = $f->buttons;
my $referrer = $f->referer;

print "Name: ", $name, "\nLink: ", $links, "\nFields: ", @fields,"\nButtons: ", $buttons, "\nReferrer: ", $referrer;

my $response = $mech->request($f->press("ok"));
my $cookie = $cookie_jar->extract_cookies($response);
print $response->content if $response->is_success;

print "Succesfully got url" if $mech->success;

#my $headers = new HTTP::Headers;
#my $cookie = $headers->header('Cookie:');
#print "Cookie:", $headers->referer;

#$mech->get($url);
#my @forms = $mech->forms;


#my $content = $mech->content;
my $output_content = 'MagicLogin.html';


#open Write ,">$output_content";
#print Write $content;
```

Output:

> Name: frmLoginEmbedded
> Use of uninitialized value $link in print at MagicLoginTest.pl line32.
> Link:
>
> Fields:
> Buttons: 0
> Use of uninitialized value $referre in print at MagicLoginTest.pl line 37.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I edited out the second question/unrelated problem. It is better to [open a seperate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) for that, please do so. You can simply undo my edit if you don't agree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mechanize already includes a [cookie jar](http://p3rl.org/HTTP%3a%3aCookies). You need not construct it manually.

```
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);
use WWW::Mechanize qw();
my $m = WWW::Mechanize->new;
$m->get(…);
$m->cookie_jar; # returns a HTTP::Cookies object
# e.g.
print $m->cookie_jar->as_string;
$m->cookie_jar->scan(sub { print Dumper \@_; })
```

Comment: It dumps the arguments to the anonymous callback. See method `scan` in the documentation I already linked to.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following snippet to access cookies:

```
my $jar = HTTP::Cookies->new();
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new(cookie_jar => $jar);
$mech->get('http://www.example.com');
# $jar now contains any cookies set during the GET
print $jar->as_string(), "\n";
```